# Why word "because" used at starting of the sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Two Guys questioning the innocent guy for destroyed vehicle. Michael is separate guy who responsible for car wreck here.

> Guy A: How're you doing?
>
> Innocent Guy: Don't fool with me. Not in the mood.
>
> Guy B: You wrecked my car.
>
> Innocent Guy: No, Michael did. Why don't you go see him? That'd be a
>   matchup.
>
> Guy A: **Because** we want you.

Comment: Because it answers the question "Why don't you go see him".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you expecting as an answer to your question? "Because" is the usual answer to a "why" question. This is similar to other languages. For example, in Spanish (as far as I know), "por qué" starts a "why" question, and "porque" starts a "because" answer.

Now, maybe you know that "because" answers "why". However, you also noticed that "Because we want you" is not a complete sentence, and that is the real intent of your question. Or maybe it isn't. I'll answer that question too, anyway. The complete sentence that means the same thing as "Because we want you" is "I didn't go see him because we want you." The because is still there, it is just a complete sentence now. In informal (usually spoken) English, people don't try to follow rules as much as they try to make sense, and that makes complete sense: "Why x?" -> "Because y."